# Strange expression in the return statement

Tags: c, recursion, return

I found a recursive function that left me a little surprised this function counts all negative numbers which appear in an array :

```
int count_negative(int arr[], int n)
{
  if ( n > 0 )
    return (*arr < 0) + count_negative( ++arr, n - 1 );
  return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain this line :

```
return (*arr < 0) + count_negative( ++arr, n-1 );
```

Thank you

Comment: This is a fairly poor implementation of recursion; it is not eligible to be converted to a tail call, so performance is going to suffer compared to an iterative implementation.

Comment: Doesn't this `(*arr ...) + count_negative( ++arr, ...` provoke UB?

Comment: @cdhowie: GCC seems to TCO it just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(*arr < 0)` compares first element of the array with zero. The result of the expression can be either `1` (first element is negative) or `0` (first element is positive or zero). So, the number of negative elements is the sum of this expression and the number of negative elements in the tail of the array.

Answer (score 3):

`*arr` points to the first element of `arr` array (or, more precisely, the part of the `arr` that has been passed to the function in this particular call).

`count_negative( ++arr, n-1 )` is a recursive call but because of `++arr`, inside this call we count the next element of the array and `n-1` argument, togeher with the `if ( n > 0 )` guarantees that we will count only elements inside the `arr` array.

Answer (score 2):

The principle is that instead of keeping an index on the element being inspected, since `arr` is a pointer and modifying it will not change the data, one may instead use `arr` itself as the iterator on the array data.

So, `*arr < 0` checks if the current pointed element is negative (it will yield `1` if so, `0` if not), and `++arr` increments the cursor to the next place in the array, which is then passed on recursively to check the rest of the array.

This is a very well known idea in functional languages working with lists, where you often work on the first element of the list (the *head*) and recurse on the remaining of the list (the *tail*).

Comment: Now I understand i.e. (*arr < 0) will be either 1 or 0 depending on whether it is a negative number

Comment: Exactly. `1` and `true` are the same value in C

Comment: 2 is also true ... ;-)